# What is the better approach for creating folder structure on a DDD project

Tags: domain-driven-design, directory-structure

I always use the same folder structure for all my domain-driven projects:

```
entities
 - UserEntity.ts
 - OrgEntity.ts
repositories
 - UserRepo.ts
services
  - (and so on)
```

But I always wonder if it's a good way to organize the project or the other way like this:

```
users
 - UserEntity.ts
 - UserRepo.ts
 - UserService.ts
orgs
 - (anything belongs to Org)
```

Is there any pros and cons and example of using both of these? Or any advice of what should be proper, better approach?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 4):

I call the first variant the **IKEA** structure:

- there's a department for lamps
- there's a department for chairs
- and so on.

The second variant is more **feel at home** style, where each room can have lamps and chairs and other furniture. It's more domain oriented, as each domain part (room) can have these aspects (lamps and furniture).

For more complex applications, you can have the domain-first variant and then further structure within each domain package, so you get the best of both variants:

```
user
- persistence
  - UserRepository.ts
  - UserEntity.ts
- service
  - UserService.ts
  - UserDTO.ts
  - NoSuchUserException.ts
org
- persistence
  - OrgRepository.ts
  - OrgEntity.ts
...
```

I usually go one step further (though with Java/Kotlin and not with Typescript), and create **submodules** within my application for each subdomain. That way, I can ship the submodules as one application (**modular monolith**) or just as well bundle them to individual applications (**microservices**) if I want to. Also this allows me to enable parallel build, where the submodules can be built and tested in **parallel**, reducing build time significantly.

Shared classes between each domain (e.g. a BaseEntity) can be put into a shared submodule (DDD: **shared kernel**).

Answer (score 0):

The second approach is better in my eyes (and the eyes of many others). The idea is that each directory/package has files that are related to each other rather than because of the layer (at least in the domain). The approach I use and see other people use which uses uses Ports and Adapters too, is similar to this:

```
- Domain Model
  - (Domain area: Application Service, Root aggregate, Repository interface, etc)
  - Users
    - All domain files related to users.
  - Common
    - Components common across multiple domain areas.
      If many components work together, I would put them in their own
      folder and given it a proper name.
- Adapters
  - Primary (triggers coming into the application)
    - (for example http controllers)
    - Users
      - GetUserController
      - (API DTOs)
  - Secondary (adapters going out of the service)
    - (for example repository implementations)
    - Users
      - UserRepository
      - (Any other supporting components).
```

A few notes:

- I try to make the domain area (not sure how to call them) have no dependency across them. This helps to prevent one change have a large blast radius.
- I might not split the adapters in primary/secondary, but still separate per domain area (so one folder for both primary and secondary adapters)